# Error : SQLSTATE[HY000] Field 'comment_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (..)

Tags: php, foreign-keys, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

i'm using laravel 6, it seems that i can't add fields to the product table , i get this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'comment_id' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`name`, `detail`, `price`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`)

this is my store action in ProductController :

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function store(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'detail' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
    ]);

    Product::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('products.index')
                    ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
}
```

this is the Product model :

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'detail', 'price', 'comment_id'
];

/**
 * The has Many Relationship
 *
 * @var array
 */
public function prodComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProdComments::class)->whereNull('parent_id');;
}
```

And comment_id is a foreign key and it refers to the primaryKey in ProdComments table...

Please help get this working !

Comment: If you don't always want to insert a comment_id, then you need to define it as nullable.

Comment: i defined it as nullable but i still get the same error :'(

Comment: Can you show your migration? If you added the nullable after you ran the migration, you'll have to rollback and rerun it.

Comment: oh okay it is working thank you